# wrapping ggplot around a function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following code which seems to work well when I just have it as below

```
      p<-ggplot(data=x.all.ER, aes(x=Year, y=value, fill = (factor(x.all.ER$Strategy))))+ 
      geom_bar(stat = 'identity',position = 'dodge', colour = "black") +
      scale_fill_manual(values = mycols) +
      scale_y_continuous(breaks=  seq(-0.3,0.3,by=0.025), labels = percent) +
      ylab("ERET") + theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size=15, face = "bold"))+
      xlab("YEAR") + theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size=15, face = "bold"))
      print(p)
```

But when I try to wrap this around another function it gives me errors. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
      mybar<-function(DS, x, y, fillby, labels, mycols, xlabel, xbreaks, 
                                                            ylabel, title)
          {
     #my.cols =c("#F7FBFF", "#DEEBF7", "#C6DBEF", "#9ECAE1", "#6BAED6", 
             # "#000000","#2171B5")

      p<-ggplot(data=DS, aes(x=x, y=y, fill = fillby)+ 
              geom_bar(stat = 'identity',position = 'dodge', colour = "black") + 
              scale_fill_manual(values = mycols) +
              scale_y_continuous(breaks=  xbreaks, labels = percent) +
              ylab(ylabel) + 
              theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size=15, face = "bold"))+   
              xlab(xlabel) + 
              theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size=15, face = "bold"))
              print(p)
        }
```

Comment: You will more than likely want `aes_string` in the function. Maybe this question can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20494238/implementing-geom-options-from-a-custom-function/22826702#22826702 (There will be other/better answers on SO about this)

Comment: In your first plot - what are you plotting? Is it the maximum 'value' for each 'year' / 'strategy' combination ?

Comment: For starters you have a missing paren in the call to `ggplot(...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can type `x=x` instead of `x="x"` in ggplot2 because the `DS` data.frame is essentially attached within the function (see `?with` to get some idea of what's going on). Your call to `ggplot` is looking for a variable named `fillby` in the `DS` data frame, but there isn't one. As recommended in the comments, the way to get around this is with the `aes_string` function.

```
library(ggplot2)
df = data.frame( xx=1:10, yy=1:10+rnorm(10) )

# Regular use of ggplot
ggplot(df,aes(x=xx,y=yy)) + geom_point()

# wrapping ggplot in another function
myggplot = function( DF, x, y) {
  ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point()
}
myggplot(df,x,y)
## Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'x' not found
```

The problem is that ggplot is looking for the `x` column in the data.frame because of the `ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y))` in `myggplot`. Note that this will work just fine.

```
names(df) = c("x","y")
myggplot(df,x,y)
```

but so will this.

```
names(df) = c("x","y")
myggplot(df,NULL,NA)
```

The fix:

```
df = data.frame( xx=1:10, yy=1:10+rnorm(10) )
myggplot2 = function( DF, x, y) {
  ggplot(df,aes_string(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point()
}
myggplot2(df,"xx","yy")
```

If you want to avoid having to write quotes, then do

```
myggplot3 = function( DF, x, y) {
  ggplot(df,aes_string(x=deparse(substitute(x)),
                       y=deparse(substitute(y)))) + geom_point()

}
myggplot3(df,xx,yy)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `aes_string(...)` instead of `aes(...)`, as in the other answer, is the idiomatic way to do this. I actually prefer a slightly different approach:

```
mybar<-function(DS, x, y, fillby, label, mycols, xlabel, xbreaks, 
                ylabel, title) {
  require(ggplot2)
  gg <- data.frame(x=DS[,x],y=DS[,y],fill=DS[,fillby])
  p<-ggplot(gg, aes(x=x, y=y, fill = fill))+ 
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity',position = 'dodge', colour = "black") + 
    scale_fill_manual(values = mycols) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks=  xbreaks, labels = percent) +
    ylab(ylabel) + 
    theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size=15, face = "bold"))+   
    xlab(xlabel) + 
    theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size=15, face = "bold"))
  print(p)         
}
```

This is the same as yours except that a new df is created in the function. This is slower (slightly) but has the advantage that you can pass either column names or column numbers as `x`, `y`, and `fillby`.

Note also that you pass the argument `label` but don't seem to do anything with it.